# Java String vs. Command Line Argument

Tags: java, string, command-line-arguments, backslash

Why does it happen that a command line argument passed to a Java class seems to be automagically escaped while in an instantiated String object the escape character () is seemingly ignored.

For example, if start with a string like this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_col like 'ABC_\' ESCAPE '\'
```

And I try running it through a simple class like this:

```
public class EscapeTest {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String str = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE " 
                     + "my_col like 'ABC_\' ESCAPE '\'";
        System.out.println("ARGS[0]: "+args[0]);
        System.out.println("STR: "+str);
}
}
```

and I pass the "SELECT" statement above in as a command line arg, I get output that looks like this:

```
ARGS[0]: SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_col like 'ABC_\' ESCAPE '\'

STR: SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_col like 'ABC_' ESCAPE ''
```

If I look at the value of ARGS[0] in the Eclipse debugger I see that the slashes are escaped. Why does this happen? Makes it kind of hard to predict I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contents of your string `str` does not contain any backslashes. Those are being handled by the Java compiler understanding the escape sequences of Java string literals.

The command line processor presumably *isn't* doing that - it's not treating backslash specially in any way, although this will depend on your shell. (In most Unix shells it *would* treat backslash differently. My guess is that you're on Windows.)

So, your command line argument *does* have backslashes in. They haven't been escaped by the executing Java process - they're just "there" in the string.

Now it sounds like the *debugger* is escaping the string when it's displaying it to you, so that you can see things like tabs and newlines. It's important to understand that this is *just* the way the debugger displays the string - there's no such thing as an "escape" within a Java string itself.

EDIT: As per comment:

To express this string in Java source code, you have to escape the backslashes:

```
String str = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_col like 'ABC_\\' ESCAPE '\\'";
```

Backslashes have to be escaped as backslash is the escape character in Java string literals.

Comment: To perhaps clarify your correct answer: to express this string in Java source code, you indeed have to write: `String str = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_col like 'ABC_\\' ESCAPE '\\'";` Backslashes must be escaped since they are the escape character in a Java source String literal.

Comment: I'm actually running this on a Mac, so effectively Unix. Running inside Eclipse and from and terminal (unix CLI) produce the same result. I understand about escaping the escape character in he String instantiation in the Java source, I was just attempting to show a one-to-one comparison.

Comment: @Jason: If you're running in the terminal, I would expect the shell to be handling treating the backslash as an escape character. Could you show your *exact* command-line? (Running inside Eclipse I can understand being somewhat different.)

Comment: @Jon: Here is my exact command line:
    java org.jason.string.EscapeTest "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_col like 'ABC_\' ESCAPE '\'"

Comment: @Jon: Here is the exact command line 
`java org.jason.string.EscapeTest "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_col like 'ABC_\' ESCAPE '\'"`

Comment: @Jason: It must be the double quotes which are avoiding the backslashes being quoted. I *thought* only single quotes did that, but I can never remember the details of bash escaping...