# FileNotfound exception in simple java code

Tags: java

I'm using this code to read a file in java using the filereader object. However the application throws an exception stating that it is not able to find the file.Can anyone help this novice guy just into java programming

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;


public class CFileReader {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)  throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        String objLine;
        String strInputFileName;
        FileReader objReader = null;
        Scanner objScanner;
        File objFile;

        if(args.length > 0)
        {
            for(int i = 0;i < args.length ;i++)
            {
                //Gets the arguments into the strInputFileName variable
                strInputFileName = args[i];

                System.out.println("Filename entered was : " + strInputFileName);

                //Create a file object which points to the filename i.e strInputFileName 
                objFile = new File(strInputFileName);

                //Create a FileReader object with the File object i.e objFile as the input parameter
                objReader = new FileReader(objFile);

                System.out.println("Filereader object is : " + objReader.toString());

                //Create a scanner object with FileReader as input parameter
                objScanner = new Scanner(objReader);

                System.out.println(args);


                //Scans the file if it has next line
                while(objScanner.hasNextLine())
                {
                    //Store the contents i.e. first line in the objLine Variable
                    objLine = objScanner.nextLine();


                    //prints the contents
                    if(objLine.indexOf(i) > 0)
                        {
                            System.out.println(objLine);
                        }
                }


            }

        }
        else
        {
            //Warn the user to enter the command line arguments if he has not entered
            System.out.println("Please Enter Command line args");
        }

    }

}
```

To compile the program i use

```
javac CFileReader.java
```

and to run

```
java CFileReader "C:\\Hello.txt"
```

where **Hello.txt** is a simple text file with some contents

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Can you print the stacktrace ( the error message ? )

Comment: Does `Hello.txt` exist in your (root) `C:` directory? and do you really need the double \\ there? (not 100% sure about the latter).

Comment: One thing to check: Try printing out `objFile.getAbsolutePath()` (right after you create the File) and see if it is what you expect. I'm not sure how those \\'s will parse at the command line.

Comment: Stacktrace ...........Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Hello.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at CFileReader.main(CFileReader.java:35)

Comment: look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794908/java-string-vs-command-line-argument)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the args[0] error pointed out by @Adel, you also don't have to escape the "\" in the command line...  "C:\Hello.txt" is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `\\`. Java doesn't parse escape sequences in input strings, and the single backslash is a path separator in the Windows shell.

Answer (score 0):

I generally put in the following lines between my File object and its use:

```
if (!objFile.isFile() || !objFile.exists()) {
  System.out.println("Could not find file: " + objFile.getPath().toString();
}
```

this will often show a problem in the string format of the file name.

Comment: i used this snippet but the application is not throwing any exception at this stage but only when i try to read the file using the filereader object

Comment: if this doesn't show anything, then there is an actual problem reading the file - the file is valid but can not be read. If I had to guess, I'd say permissions?  Because as far as I can tell the rest is set up correctly.  I'd check to make sure the file you were trying to read was something that had open permissions.  I've never used the scanner object however, it could have restrictions or I may not know its usage.

Comment: Any idea of special handling incase of Windows 7 OS ??

Answer (score 0):

That code works in my MacOS system, The problem is the way in what your write the path of you file in Windows. In my case:

```
java CFileReader /home/jenaiz/test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I compiled and tested this code myself on Windows, and it works fine. Either the file you are after does not exist, or you are making a mistake when you type in the name of the file on the command line.

Comment: Strange i'm still not able to run this x(

Comment: Are you 100% sure the file you are trying to use exists?

Answer (score 0):

Check that your input file actually exists.  When I ran your code on my machine, I didn't have permission to create a file in the root of C:.  How did you create your test file?

When I moved the file to another drive, e.g. "t:\hello.txt" it worked the first time.

Comment: i tried using the test file on "D" Drive..BUt still the prog is not able to search n locate the file :(

Comment: Try moving the file to the same directory where your source is located.  That way you know you have read/write permissions and can rule that out.